# Neo4j query combining data from Elasticsearch for time based graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Neo4j and Cypher gurus,

I am using Neo4j, Elasticsearch and Spring Data Neo4j. I have entity nodes which are related to each other. On the relationship there is a count field which is the total number of relationships between two entities. I am using the following Cypher to bring back the top 50 relationships for a entity:

```
MATCH (e1:Entity)-[r1:RELATED_TO]-(e2:Entity)
WHERE e1.uuid = '<ENTITY_ID>'
RETURN e1,r1,e2
ORDER BY r1.count DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Now what I would like to do is visualise a time based graph for the entity by bringing back the top 50 relationships for the last week (last month etc). I am not storing time series data in Neo4j, only the total count for the relationship. The time series data is stored in an Elasticsearch index with the following format.

`Date, entityOrRelationshipId, startId, endId, type`

Each time a relationship is updated, a row is inserted into the index with the datetime, relationshipId and entityId.

The relationship count can be searched and aggregated using the following Elasticsearch query:

```
GET localhost:9200/trends/_search

{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "type": "RELATIONSHIP"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "date": {
                            "gte": "2020-04-01T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                            "lt": "2020-04-28T00:00:00.000+00:00"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            { "term": { "startId": "<ENTITY_ID>"} },
                            { "term": { "endId": "<ENTITY_ID>" } }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "my_rels": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "entityOrRelationshipId",
                "size": 50
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following results with counts (doc_count) for each relationship id for a certain date range:

```
{
    "took": 5,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2273,
        "max_score": 0.0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "my_rels": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 145,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "2fa94be4-828b-4a20-b5f8-4965d5516149",
                    "doc_count": 303
                },
                {
                    "key": "74fb5f46-a6e8-41a8-bd11-cb374324b285",
                    "doc_count": 197
                },
                {
                    "key": "dc57fdcf-ea88-4808-9310-4e09d368e743",
                    "doc_count": 178
                },
                {
                    "key": "c4fbda1f-717e-4422-bc10-66ca6a6f39d7",
                    "doc_count": 79
                },
                etc.

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Using the Neo4J APOC library, how would I combine the Elasticsearch count results into my Cypher query without having to store the count values in Neo4J?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that:

- `RELATED_TO` relationships have a `uuid` property for the relationship id, and
- the `Entity` id and the "buckets" list are passed to the query as the [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) `entityId` and `buckets`, this should work:

  ```
  UNWIND $buckets AS b
  MATCH (e1:Entity)-[r1:RELATED_TO]-(e2)
  WHERE e1.uuid = $entityId AND r1.uuid = b.key
  RETURN e1, r1, e2, b.doc_count AS count
  ORDER BY count DESC
  ```

The `LIMIT` clause is not needed, since the number of result rows will be determined by the size of the `buckets` list.

Comment: Thanks cybersam, let me give it a try. I assume that `$buckets` will be the response from the Elasticsearch query. I also overlooked something, the entities also have a `count` field which will need to be time based too. The data for entities is also stored in the same index. I will need to check if I can get this info in the same ElasticSearch query but would it be possible in the above Cypher query to also return the elastic search entity counts as well (i.e. for e1 and e2)?

Comment: `buckets` will be `aggregations.my_rels.buckets` in the Elasticsearch result. Your Elasticsearch will have to provide the time-based entity counts, since your entities presumably do not maintain daily count data. You should consider whether your hybrid database approach is really worth it.

Comment: OK so I wouldn't be able to replace the quey returned e1.count field value with the elastic search timebased entity count value? I was looking at alternatives ways to do this, I concluded that if I had to do this with Neo4j, I would have to probably create time based versions of the entities and multiple time based relationships between the entities.

Comment: There are several ways you can replace the returned `e1.count` field. But it may indeed be better to modify your neo4j data model to store the time-based info.

Comment: I managed to get this all working in end and the response times are quite rapid. Thanks for the support.